# How do I climb the Broadway church?

Tags: forza-horizon-4

I have been trying to collect all of the Fast Travel bonus boards in Forza Horizon 4, which will allow me to use the Fast Travel feature for free. Most have been easy, but I recently spotted this one on top of a church in Broadway, on the south side of the map, and can't figure out how to reach it.

[image: Screenshot of Forza Horizon 4 showing a sign balanced on top of a church, as seen from the perspective of a driver in the car]

I've seen a few other bonus boards located on top of obstacles, but none were this high, and they all had some obvious ramp-like feature nearby to jump from. There doesn't seem to be anything like that near the church.

How do I obtain the Fast Travel bonus board on top of the church in Brodway?

Comment: Usually there is a jump nearby. Line it up, jump, and if you don't hit rewind and go again, and again, and again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ramp for that board is actually a danger sign jump.

The jump, from your picture location is directly to your left just behind some trees in the middle of a grassy (or snowy during winter) patch.

[image]

You need to reach a certain rank in order to unlock the jump, I think it may be rank 5? I am not sure if it shows up until it is unlocked, it is a standalone ramp (not part of the map itself).

Unfortunately, until then, it is not possible to reach that fast travel board.

Comment: Aha. The ramp appeared to me yesterday, and I got the board, but I wasn't sure what caused it to appear. I guessed it might have been the switchover from Winter to Spring, but ranking up makes more sense. Thanks